# Is there a chart showing all building and their prerequisites in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

While playing Civilization V on my PC, I noticed that some buildings are not shown or cannot be built unless you already have another building in that city.

Example: A shrine is required to construct a temple.

Comment: aka you want a building tech tree

Comment: Not exactly, just like the example, you can't build Temple in a city without the a shrine.

Comment: which means in the temple tree the shrine is a prerequisite for the temple, putting all that together gives a tree of possible paths, this is usually called a tech tree

Comment: ahh... I see, I didn't noticed that. But I think that's what I want to see.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All of the building tech trees in Civilization 5 are dead-simple. To build the next Science building, you need the previous Science building. To build the next Culture building, you need the previous Culture building. All of the buildings that require particular resources or nearby tiles have no prerequisites. As you've probably discovered by now, the later buildings get *really* expensive for relatively-small gains, but they're worth it if you've chosen to specialize your cities.

Here's the chart:

**Science**

Library -> University -> Public School -> Research Lab

Observatory (requires only mountain adjacent to city)

**Faith (Gods & Kings or later)**

Shrine -> Temple

**Culture**

Monument -> Amphitheater -> Opera House -> Museum -> Broadcast Tower

**Money**

Market -> Bank -> Stock Exchange

Mint (requires only gold or silver)

**Production**

Workshop -> Factory

Forge (requires only iron)

Stone Works (requires only stone)

Stable (requires only horses)

Windmill (requires city *not* being on a hill)

Water Mill (requires only river adjacent to city)

Lighthouse (requires coastal city)

Harbor -> Seaport (requires coastal city; harbor provides no hammers in BNW)

Hydro Plant (city must be adjacent to river)

Solar Plant (city must be adjacent to desert or on one, and not have a Nuclear Plant)

Nuclear Plant (city must not have a Solar Plant)

**Food**

Aqueduct -> Hospital -> Medical Lab

Granary

**Happiness**

Colosseum -> Theatre/Zoo -> Stadium

Stone Works (requires only stone)

Circus (requires only horses or elephants)

**Defense**

Walls -> Castle -> Arsenal -> Military Base

Bomb Shelter (defense against nukes only)

**Increase XP of units**

Barracks -> Armory -> Military Academy

Comment: As I read it again, I didn't know about the Solar Plant and Nuclear Power Plant.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *exactly* a building tech tree, but the [List of buildings in Civ5](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_buildings_in_Civ5) wiki page contains all buildings and whatever prerequisites or requirements they might have (in the Notes section).